# Getting a count of Top level Categories WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

i am trying to get a count of top level categories , i am using wordpress 2016 theme , its a static front page and i am trying to retrieve the total count of categories and then dynamically create table with those categories

i tried to search with WP_Query and wp_list_categories  it does list names but not the total count , i tried to use count function in php but output is always 0(zero) even though i have few categories / posts etc already created to test this functionality.

please advise or assist with the code

Thanks

Comment: Are you want top level category list with post count or total category count of top level?

Comment: Hi , yes i am exactly looking for that as well count of categories to divide and place them in a table 3 in each row.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below Code :

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'parent' => 0,
  'hide_empty' => 0
  );

$categories = get_categories( $args );

echo count( $categories );   
?>
```

You can also wrap it in a function to re-use it else where in your site.

Hope this will help you!